# Change package import path

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I have the following situation:

```
<some_path>
   |-<packageA>
   |     |-__init__.py
   |     |
   |     |-<subpackageB>
   |     |       |-__init__.py
   |     |
   |     |-<subpackageC>
   |     |       |-__init__.py
```

The path pointing to "packageA" is in my PYTHONPATH environment variable. Because of other reasons I want to avoid placing "some_path" in PYTHONPATH.

Right now, if I want to import "subpackageB" from somwhere I write

```
import subpackageB
```

I would like to avoid that, to avoid name collisions I need the import's logical path to be:

```
import packageA.subpackageB
```

I am wondering if there is any way of doing this, maybe with the __init__.py placed in "packageA" directory.
Is there any way of achieving this with the current directory layout?

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone? I still have not figured this out... :(

Comment: Isn't there any way to do this?